# Cocoa Bindings not updating NSTextField value

Tags: core-data, cocoa-bindings

I have two windows, one is a table view to display content. One is a window for inputting content.

I have an NSTextField binded to a property in my app delegate. When I change a value in the text field, the app delegate property will change. However, if I go the other way and programmatically change the property's binded key, the value of the text field does not update. However, it does in the table view.

What is going wrong here? How can I update text field?

EDIT:

I tried all 3 of these with the same result

```
[_addEntry setValue:@"Chet" forKey:@"payee"];
[_addEntry setPayee:@"chet"];
_addEntry.payee = @"chet";
```

EDIT:

Here's a simple example to elaborate on my point

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48014761/test.zip

the label and the textfield are bound to the "str" property. It is initially null. press log to see that in the console. press change str button to change the string. Log to verify. Note that the label and the textfield do not update!

EDIT:

"What am I trying to accomplish?"

Here's the project I am working with:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48014761/Write-Offs.zip

I am trying to use Cocoa Bindings as much as possible. I have a table with a bunch of data. However, each entry is going to have an array of images associated with it. Thus, when I add a new entry, I need to open up a new window so I can set the properties of that entry (rather than through the table) along with upload some images.

I am not sure I am implementing the addEntryWindow correctly. It seems like I should create and destroy the window each time I open and close it. This doesn't appear to be happening.

Also, `[[self addEntry] setDate:[NSDate date]];` doesn't seem to fix the problem for me.

Thanks

Chet

Answer (score 1):

How are you programmatically changing the field?  Are you using KVO?  Is the field inside of a `NSManagedObject` instance?

Bindings work through KVO.  Core Data disables some aspects of KVO for its own internal uses and you might be tripping over one of those.

Update your question with the code sample and lets see what is going on.

### Update

Both windows don't necessarily need to be in the same xib but they do need to be talking to the same instances.  Ideally they should both be talking to the same instance of `NSManagedObject` and therefore talking to the same `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Who is the owner of each window?

Is the owner the same?

If not, is a new Core Data stack being created?

### Update

In your test, I was able to correct it by how you were editing the property

```
- (IBAction)press:(id)sender {

  [self setStr:@"this"];
}
```

You were accessing the iVar directly instead of the property.  When you access the iVar directly KVO does not fire.

In addition, in your xib files you were accessing `self.str` which is unnecessary.  It should be just `str`.

Are you doing any direct property access in your actual project?

### Update

You can do a get accessor and then a set accessor:

```
[[self addEntry] setPayee:xxx];
```

Based on the variables you are using I wonder what you are trying to accomplish.  Can you post the exact code of the programmatic change you are trying to enact?

Comment: I edited... Maybe I am doing things wrong - should both windows be in the same xib file?

Comment: check my new edit - also, not sure how to determine who the "owner" of each window is... They're both in the MainMenu.xib file

Comment: Its all pointing to the same nsmanagedobjectcontext. When I change something in the entry window, the table does change...

Comment: Ah. Well I am trying to set a property of the property. I can't exactly do [self setAddEntry.payee: "chet"]...

Comment: So I think I was just messing up how I was implementing the multiple windows. I created a new .xib and NSWindowController for the second window. This fixed everything...